# Tensorflow Control Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm creating a Convolutional Neural Network for image classification. I'm new to Tensorflow and just to get a hang of its control flow, I put a simple "Hello World" print statement inside conv_net(). However, when I run the program, the output is

```
Hello World!
Epoch 0 completed out of 5 Loss: 0.959831058979
Epoch 1 completed out of 5 Loss: 1.15144479275
Epoch 2 completed out of 5 Loss: 1.15144479275
Epoch 3 completed out of 5 Loss: 1.35144472122
Epoch 4 completed out of 5 Loss: 1.15144479275
```

This means that conv_net() is only getting executed once, as opposed to NUM_EPOCHS times. Why is this so? Below is a snippet of my program,

```
def conv_net(x):
    print("Hello World!")

    with tf.variable_scope("ConvNet"):
        # First Layer
        w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([11, 11, 3, 96], stddev=0.03))
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([96]))
        conv2d_layer1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w1, [1, 4, 4, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv2d_layer1 += b1
        conv2d_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_layer1)
        conv2d_layer1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2d_layer1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        … 

    return y

def main():
    img_batch, lbl_batch = input_pipeline()
    prediction = conv_net(img_batch)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction, 
                                                                    labels=tf.one_hot(lbl_batch, NUM_CLASSES)))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:  
        sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()))
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(train_size/BATCH_SIZE)):
                c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer])
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', NUM_EPOCHS, 'Loss:', epoch_loss)

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Why would you expect the function to be executed multiple times? You only call it once, outside of the loop.

Comment: Well I do run "cost" which should call "prediction" and subsequently the flow of control should go within conv_net(). That's how tensorflow works

Comment: No, it isn't. The net will be built at the start - it won't be continually rebuilt. Remember, the python you are writing is essentially going to be mapped to c code that is then actually run.

Comment: Actually, though, that doesn't even matter here. When prediction is created, it's just whatever you return from `conv_net`. It has no link to the original function anymore, it's just whatever the object that you return from it is. Tensorflow will have no knowledge of how it was created.